# Why my function doesn't work? (Assembly)

Tags: assembly

I wanted to make a function which will print on the screen an array called sol. The distance between each char should be located 3 "chars" from ech other.
 **But**, when I run my code only the first line of the array is printed.

Here is my Dseg code:

```
line db 0
col db 0
temp db 3
indexc dw 0
sol db   'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'
S_LEN = $- sol
            db   'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p'
            db   '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*'
            db   '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*'
            db   '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*'
            db   '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*'
            db   'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p'
            db   'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'
S_LEN2 = $- sol
```

my function is:

```
 PutPlayers Proc    
    push ax bx cx dx si

InitiolazingVar:

    mov temp, offset sol
    mov line, 1
    mov col, 1
    mov si, 1
Again:  
    ;location 
        mov dl, col
        mov dh, line
        mov bx, 0
        mov ah, 2h
        int 10h



    ;printing the char
        mov al, ds:[temp][si]
        mov bl, 33
        mov cx, 1h
        mov bh, 0
        mov ah, 9h
        int 10h

        add col, 3h
        inc si
        cmp si, 9
        jnz Again


        add temp, S_LEN
        mov si, 1h
        mov col, 1h
        add line, 3h

        cmp line, 19h
        jnz Again

        pop si dx cx bx ax
        ret
PutPlayers endp
```

So, can you please help me?

Comment: `[temp][si]` means `[temp+si]`, _not_ `[[temp] + si]`. What you probably want is `[sol][si]`. Also, your index (`si`) is incorrect: it should go from 0 to 7, not from 1 to 8 (think of the base address plus _zero_ as the _first_ element).

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, I don't like the instruction:

```
mov al, ds:[temp][si]
```

I think you are expecting that it will read a byte from the address equal to the sum of **content** of [temp] and the content of SI.

But it is not the case. This instruction, actually use the address_of_temp+si. The content of [temp] is not used.

Here I would suggest to use only si as a pointer and think about other comparisons about loop end.